# What is ADO.NET provider model ?

Tags: .net, ado.net

How exactly should you approach this question if you're asked this on .NET interview.

I tried to google it, but haven't found any suitable answer. As I'm pretty sure that I don't understand this question - but this is one of the questions that's being asked.

If anyone could explain this (the more the better) or paste some url with explanation, that would be great : )

What's the relationship with ASP.NET provider model ?

Comment: Found that as well, but from this it implies that this question is equivalent to the general one - What is ADO.NET.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about a programming problem

Comment: It really depends on the intention of the interviewer, as if it were me I would expect the candidate to answer something like this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx Microsoft tries to emphasize that as a design pattern. Throughout .NET Framework (not only ASP.NET and ADO.NET) you can find other provider cases as well.